# Getting the url of an uploaded file in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have an application in which I am uploading a file using Django's admin site. I need to return the url of the file so that it can be used by another function. The process works just fine apart from the fact that I am able to get the name of the original file and not the file that is saved by the application. For instance if the file to be uploaded is named somefile.xxx and django saves it as somefile_1.xxx because that somefile.xxx already exists on the server I am not able to return somefile_1.xxx but I am geting the original file name. this is my code at the moment.

admin.py

```
def add_view(self, request, form_url="", extra_context=None):
        ...

        ModelForm = self.get_form(request)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if form.is_valid():
                url = MEDIA_URL+'files/'+request.FILES['filename'].name
                url = iri_to_uri(url)
                title = form.cleaned_data['title']
                name = request.FILES['filename'].name
                newname = os.path.splitext(request.FILES['filename'].name)[0]
                data = utils.convert(url, title, newname)
                print data

        return super(FileAdmin, self).add_view(request, form_url="", extra_context=extra_context)
```

**Solution:**

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):

        ...

        obj.save()

        url = obj.video.url

        title = obj.title

        newname = str(obj.id)

        data = utils.convert(url, title, newname)
        print data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `add_view` is pre save - so the files should be in memory and thus no filenames should be set yet.

You'd need to override `ModelAdmin.save_model` and access the file after calling `obj.save()` to account for the possibility that django renamed your file.

Answer (score 1):

FileField has an url function to retrieve exactly what you want i guess
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.storage

See the point 3 under the storage section